# Gitlab password and permission

Tags: git, ssh, passwords, gitlab

I have a small problem with a Gitlab installation and SSH commands as we just installed this thing on Debian.

I followed and used Gitlabs Omnibus installation so Gitlab is somehere at /var/opt/gitlab/. After some tweaking, we got it to work fine. Problems occur now that I attempt to push the first project to origin master. First problem was when I attempted to used my own username as the remote url as

```
username@gitlab.address.com:/full/path/to/repo.git
```

I changed it now to git@ as I realized it needs to be git since the repo folder git uses is under git:git permissions. You cant overwrite those files without proper permissions on the server.

Now when I attempt to push it asks me for my passphrase on my username via the

```
/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
```

path. This is weird. I can skip this by just hitting enter, but after that it asks for git@gitlab.address.com password.

I have not set this.

What makes this even more weird is that when I try

```
ssh git@git.address.com
```

This command asks for my username passphrase at /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa again. When I write it, it lets me log in and welcomes me with my real name.

I also tried sudo passwd git, changed the password, then tried to push skipping my passphrase and just entering git@gitlab.access.com password. Did not work. Says Access denied.

What is wrong here and how can I fix this?

Comment: It doesn't look like anything is wrong; this all sounds like normal operations. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Problem is when I push I get Access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't push to `/full/path/to/git/repo.git` as if it is just a plain old Git repository residing in a plain old directory in your Git server.

GitLab is a Git hosting service like GitHub, the only difference is you can host it on your own metal or VPS. You don't try to find the actual location where GitHub stores your repository and try to push to there, do you? Same workflow should be applied to GitLab as well.

You should add your SSH Public Key to your GitLab account and then create a repository from inside GitLab. Once you do that, GitLab will provide you with the address to be used. It will look something like this:

```
git@gitlab.example.com/[project-group|repository-owner]/repository.git
```

For an example, if the project "My Awesome Project" is owned by "John Doe" with user name "johnd", it'll look like `git@gitlab.example.com/johnd/my-awesome-project.git`. If it is owned by a project group name "Ultra Secret" and it's name is "Project X 215", it'll look like `git@gitlab.example.com/ultra-secret/project-x-215.git`.

Now you can add that address as a remote of your existing repository, or clone it to create a new empty repository.

And then you can push and pull as you wish!

Comment: You were right. I was thinking this a littlebit wrong, but we also had some permission problems (which I caused). I backtraced it all and reconfigured stuff, now the pushes and everything work fine. Thank you.

Comment: @Rcls: I am glad you were able to get it right. I hope you'd fall in love with GitLab soon, just as I did. :)